# I'm not able to view the total length of the recorded video and the timelines

Tags: video, html5-canvas, webrtc, blob, recordrtc

I need help with a limitation that I am facing.
Technical Stack: Angular 7, HTML5, Microsoft Azure Blob Storage, RecordRTC
I am trying to record a video using the HTML5 video tag which gets stored into local storage in a Blob format using RecordRTC. However, when playing the same, I'm not able to view the total length of the recorded video and the timelines. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known issue with webm files generated by the MediaRecorder API having wrong metadata. https://github.com/legokichi/ts-ebml/issues/14 shows how to fix the metadata.

Comment: https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/issues/147 This url solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Currently I have a solution based on ts-ebml, you can try the npm package `webm-duration-fix`, which uses blob.stream to solve the repair of large files as well as memory footprint problems.
https://github.com/buynao/webm-duration-fix

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).